# How to make a QLabel fill the child QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QWidget, used Lay Out in a Grid, then a QLabel, but there are some spaces between the QWidget and QLabel. How can I make them the same size and not break the layout?

I'm using this from UI editor.

Comment: Have you set the layout margin to 0 in all the axes?

Comment: Nope, I'm new to qt and GUI programming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select the widget, in the UI editor's property pane you should see the options for the layout that belongs to it (the options have a red background, and they're usually at the bottom of the list).  Amongst the options are ones for setting the margin in pixels between widgets in the layout, if you set it to 0 it should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, if I'm using label inside scrollarea or inside tableview? what should I do?

Comment: Those scenarios are different, please post a new question.

Comment: I have solved problem with layout. Added them to new layout and set margins to 0 :) Thank you!